# If row contains date, get value of other cell

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to iterate through rows in a Pandas dataframe and check if the date equals a specific date, and if it does, return the value of another cell. I figured I could create a mask to do this and then use np.where to assign True or False to those rows. I have done this in the past using strings and integers, but now that it is using a date it is not working.

If I do:

```
df[pd.to_datetime(df['birth_date']) == '1990-12-10']
```

It returns the row of the person whose birth_date is that day.

However, if I do:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    bday_mask = (pd.to_datetime(row['birth_date']) == '1990-12-10')
    df['bday_is_today'] = np.where(bday_mask, True, False)
```

It assigns every row to "False". How do I put a flag on rows if their birth date is equal to that date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't neep to iterate, just get the indices of all rows where your condition is true:

```
df["bday_is_today"] = False
bdays = df[pd.to_datetime(df['birth_date']) == '1990-12-10'].index
df.loc[bdays, 'bday_is_today'] = True
```

Comment: @Emac I am happy that it works. I suggest you accept this as an answer so that others can see that your matter is solved. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I was planning on it, SO just wouldn't let me accept it until enough time had passed. You were too quick! :)